# Can't bring up wlan0

Tags: networking, hotspot

I am trying to do a hotspot with my raspberry pi 3 (Raspbian 9.3).
I follow this tutorial : https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-wireless-hotspot-0180133/

I use hostapd and dnsmasq. I have a problem on step 3 when I need to set a static ip to wlan0.

```
$ sudo ifup wlan0
Error: inet prefix is expected rather than "192.168.197,1/255.255.255.0".
ifup: failed to bring up wlan0
```

My /etc/network/interface is

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.197,1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.197.0
    broadcast 192.168.197.255
```

Comment: What OS version are you running?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian 9

Comment: I hope you only have a typo in your example... There should not be a comma in the address of the wlan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks to be due to typo in `address 192.168.197,1` (should be `.1`).

Comment: That's an answer.  The correct one, I think, since the typo is repeated in the output of the error.